# How can I trigger push notification on real time database change using OneSignal? I have created the database using firebase service

Tags: firebase, flutter, onesignal

I am using firebase’s real time database to store objects created through my app. Now what I need is that I must be able to trigger a push notification using OneSignal whenever I add a new object to my Database. Is it feasible?

Comment: Yes, it's feasible.  If you're having problems with this, please post the code that isn't working the way you expect, and explain what it should be doing instead.

Comment: Can you suggest any external link where I can learn this from scratch?